# Netbeans 7 Remote Server Connections with PHP

Tags: php, linux, netbeans

Is this possible? I've been searching and searching and I can't find any references to the Netbeans 7 remote server support in Linux.

Comment: Is this for debugging? If you so and you're using XDebug then see http://blog.simonholywell.com/post/374203131/netbeans-and-xdebug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine, I use it all the time. However I wouldn't recommend it with large amounts of files as it fails to handle that many.